# How to fix 'from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2' error in python?

Tags: python-3.x

i get the following error in my code in pycharm when i try to import caffe_pb2 : "Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items". How can i resolve this error ?

```
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the Python console:

```
sys.path.extend([/home/user/caffe-master/python])
```

Plus, add the following lines to your code:

```
import sys
 sys.path.append("/home/user/caffe-master/python/")
 import caffe
```

This worked out for me. 
Otherwise, you can go to the project interpreter and directly add it to the python PATH. Go to Settings -> Project Interpreter -> select the specific folder that you're working on -> open the bar with all the possible interpreters and press show all -> click the last of the options -> add the path `(/home/user/caffe-master/python)`